# How does one classify monoidal biclosed structures on $Cat$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monoidal-categories

[Foltz, Kelly, and Lair](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404980900821) assert that there are exactly two monoidal biclosed structures on the 1-category $Cat$ of small categories. But most of the proof is left as an "exercise" (see Prop 4).

**Question:** How does one complete this exercise?

Notes:

- I'm not clear on exactly when Foltz, Kelly, and Lair count two monoidal biclosed structures as being "the same", but I assume that it's when there is a monoidal equivalence between the two monoidal structures $(Cat, \otimes_1) \to (Cat, \otimes_2)$ whose underlying functor is (nonmonoidally) isomorphic to the identity functor $Cat \to Cat$.
- The part of the argument which is not left as an exercise seems satisfactory -- they show that the unit of any monoidal biclosed structure on $Cat$ must be the terminal category.
- I don't know whether the statement is also true for the $(2,1)$-category $Cat$.
- The two monoidal biclosed structure are the cartesian monoidal structure, where the product of the arrow category with itself is a commutative square, and the [funny tensor product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/funny+tensor+product#:%7E:text=Funny%20tensor%20products&text=This%20makes%20Cat%20into%20a,called%20the%20funny%20tensor%20product.), where the product of the arrow category with itself is the noncommutative square.
- I'm very curious to see an analogous classification of monoidal structures on $2Cat$, which would have to include the Gray tensor product (where the product of the arrow category with itself is the lax commutative square) and its dual.

**Some first steps:**

It seems the idea is to observe that because $(\Delta^0, \Delta^1)$ is a cocategory object in $Cat$, it follows that $(\Delta^\bullet \otimes \Delta^\star)_{\bullet,\star \leq 1}$ is a co-double-category object in $Cat$, and then to try to nail down what $\Delta^1 \otimes \Delta^1$ looks like. Because $\Delta^2 = \Delta^1 \cup_{\Delta^0} \Delta^1$ is dense in $Cat$, this should basically determine at least the bicocontinuous bifunctor $\otimes$. I'm not quite sure how the associator and unitors are meant to be determined from there.

Anyway, because $\Delta^0$ is the unit and there are two canonical split monos $\Delta^0 \rightrightarrows \Delta^1$, we get that $\Delta^1 \otimes \Delta^1$ contains $\Delta^1$ as a retract in at least 4 interrelated ways. This seems to be enough to conclude that $\Delta^1 \otimes \Delta^1$ has at least 4 objects $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$, which are actually distinct. But I haven't been able to rule out that there might be *more* objects (although the retraction maps give a way to partition $Ob(\Delta^1 \otimes \Delta^1)$ into parts, each of which "belongs" to $(a,b)$ for some $a,b \in \{0,1\}$). When it comes to morphisms, the retractions also ensure that you can't have a morphism $(a,b) \to (a',b')$ unless $a \leq a', b \leq b'$. And the sections tell us that there are at least morphisms $(0,0) \rightrightarrows (0,1),(1,0) \rightrightarrows (1,1)$. But that's about all I'm able to deduce to this point.

One trick I've been trying to use is to map this co-double-category object into various other objects of $Cat$ to get an actual double category, and try to reason about it, but this hasn't gotten me very far.

**More Notes:**

- Foltz, Kelly, and Lair's description of the free noncommutative square is strange -- in the antepenultimate paragraph of the paper, they refer to it as "the full subcategory of the commutative square obtained by deleting the unique morphism $(0,0) \to (1,1)$". This description doesn't make any sense -- they should say that it's the free category on  the graph obtained from the commutative square by deleting this morphism.

Comment: This is worked out in this paper, which also treats the case of 2-Cat: http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/30/11/30-11abs.html

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Thanks, that's just what I was hoping for! If you write this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. (Although in dimension 2, Bourke and Gurski don't obtain a complete classification, they do at least list 5 known different monoidal biclosed structures on $2Cat$.) It seems the key is the observation that every cocategory object in $Set$ is a coproduct of copies of $1 \rightrightarrows 1$ and $1 \rightrightarrows 2$.